# Linked List Printing Issue

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I am attempting to print out two lists through a void function, but all I am getting is a blank for the output. The lists print fine without a void function, but I would like to understand why this is happening. Thank you.

P.S. Please disregard the mergeLists function. That is meant for another part of the problem I am working on.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *link;
};

typedef Node* NodePtr;

void headInsert(NodePtr& head, int the_number);
NodePtr mergeLists(NodePtr& firstList, NodePtr& secondList);
void outputList(NodePtr head);

int main()
{
    NodePtr firstHead, secondHead;

    headInsert(firstHead, 9);
    headInsert(firstHead, 7);
    headInsert(firstHead, 5);
    headInsert(firstHead, 3);

    outputList(firstHead);

    headInsert(secondHead, 8);
    headInsert(secondHead, 6);
    headInsert(secondHead, 4);
    headInsert(secondHead, 2);

    outputList(secondHead);

    //combinedList = mergeLists(firstHead, secondHead);

    return 0;
}

void headInsert(NodePtr& head, int number)
{
    NodePtr temp;
    temp = new Node;

    temp->data = number;

    temp->link = head;
    head = temp;
}

NodePtr mergeLists(NodePtr& firstList, NodePtr& secondList)
{
    NodePtr mainList, iter;

    for(iter = firstList; iter != NULL; iter = iter -> link)
        headInsert(mainList, iter->data);

    for(iter = secondList; iter != NULL; iter = iter -> link)
        headInsert(mainList, iter->data);

    return mainList;
}

void outputList(NodePtr head)
{
    for(NodePtr iter = head; iter != NULL; iter = iter -> link)
        cout << iter->data << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'void function'?

Comment: I think if you step through the program you'll find your problem rather quickly...

Comment: I meant the void function "outputList", which is on line 12 in my code.

Comment: Your pointers are uninitialized. They're not going to be `NULL` by default (I'm referring to every pointer you declared locally inside your functions, such as `mainList`, `firstHead`, `secondHead`, etc...)

Comment: Frecklefoot, I have been trying to draw the design out on a whiteboard for the past 30 minutes. No luck.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun Even as I add nodes to the list? I understand there will be an error if there wasn't a node there, but the outputList function is called after both lists are initialized.

Comment: It works now, thank you @MohammadAliBaydoun. So it is good practice to initialize as a NULL every time a new pointer to a list is created?

Comment: @borninla Well, it's not really about good practice or not, the reason is that when you declare a new variable like `Node* p;` on the stack, its value would be garbage data (completely arbitrary), and since you're iterating over the list when attempting to print and stopping when you hit a `NULL` pointer, I guess it's expected that you want your pointers to be initialized to `NULL` as a start (at least, because of the way you have it set up in the insertion functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, I do not see any initialization of firstHead, secondHead to NULL, so they will will never be NULL for your for loop to stop. I added the following line:

```
firstHead = secondHead = NULL;
```

after your declarations of firstHead and secondHead in the main function and it seems to work. Hope that helps